# MOSFET conducting even when no gate signal applied in bidirectional bipolar switch arrangement

Tags: mosfet-driver, powermosfet, bidirectional

I have a circuit as shown here and the expected waveforms are shown besides. When iL>0, the mosfet Q1 and diode D2 conducts the current and vice versa.   [image: bidirectional bipolar AC switch arrangement]
I see in the practical circuit implementation that the switch Q1 conducts current when no turn on voltage (Vgs1) is provided to Q1. Can someone please explain this behavior happening here. It would be really helpful. I have attached the waveforms obtained from oscilloscope to show this behaviour. The blue color waveform is a current iL through the branch shown in the circuit diagram . Ideally when iL<0, switch Q2 and diode D1 is conducting. As soon as iL=0 the switch Q1 block the voltage Vac, but what is seen from the oscilloscope is that Q1 conducts for some duration the current even when Vgs1=0V. What is the explanation for this? The diodes used here are Schottky barrier diodes.

[image: waveforms obtained from oscilloscope]

I am attaching here the driver circuit configuration.
[image]

Comment: MOSFETs are voltage controlled: "no signal applied"/ *not connected* does *not* mean the is no potential at the gate, no potential difference/voltage between gate&bulk/source.

Comment: The current spike you're asking about occurs when the current in the coil reverses. This suggests to me that your "Vgs" waveforms are not truly referenced to the common source node of the circuit. If not, when the current reverses, it pulls that node low via D1, creating a positive Vgs for Q1. Show us exactly how you are driving the gates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the driver circuit in the post for your reference. I am using a 2eds8265h dual channel driver IC from Infineon.

Comment: What are the scope waveforms? Are they measured with isolated probes? Or isolated sources? What is the purpose of the circuit? Why are the gates switching -- normally in a bidirectional switch like this, both are maintained ON together to reduce reverse conduction losses?  Where does the inductor energy go when they turn off?  What transistor type is used?

Comment: C does not matter? Why is it wired?

Comment: The scope waveforms are marked in the figure. They are measured with isolated high voltage differential probes. This circuit is similar to a thyristor controlled reactor circuit. The gates are switching as they have to block the voltage when current is zero which would not be possible otherwise. I think that when the current reaches zero during negative current cycle as seen in the ideal expected waveform, the energy in the inductor is also zero and the switch Q1 need to block the Vac. But what is seen is that current continues to flow in the positive direction through Q1 when Vgs1 is zero.

Answer (score 1):

A MOSFET has a really really well-isolated gate with a rather small capacitance.  Without a connection, the voltage will be defined by whatever charge happened to be on the gate when you last left it alone.

For small-signal MOSFETs, without a lot of precaution, this is most likely some static charge from handling it while putting it in the circuit, sometimes resulting in a high enough voltage to burn a hole in the gate.

This is the kind of device that anti-static handling instructions are written for.  Leaving the gate open is really asking for trouble.  And you'll have no idea just how much or little it will conduct, and the amount will likely change when holding your hand near the circuit.

Comment: The OP is clearly not "leaving the gate open".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to clarify the gates are not left open but are connected to the driver circuit (picture added in the post).